# Unable to retrieve object from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have integrated an edit button in my list of products, but clicking on edit button opens the form page that is unpopulated. When I console.log(p) in my product.service.ts file, it displayed null. And I think the main issue lies there.

[I am completely new in Angular, therefore any help will be appreciated].

Here is my product form template-

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
            <img [src]= "product.imageUrl" class="card-img-top" *ngIf= "product.imageUrl">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"> {{ product.title }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text"> {{ product.description }} </p>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input #title= "ngModel" [(ngModel)]= "product.title"  name = "title" id ="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                    Title is required. 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text"> ₹</span>
                    <input #price="ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "product.price" name ="price" id = "price" type="number" class="form-control " required min="0">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = "price.touched && price.invalid"> 
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div> 
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.min"> Minimum Prie should be zero. </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = ""> Price is required. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category ="ngModel" [(ngModel)] ="product.category" name = "category" id="category"  class="form-control" required>
                    <option value = ""></option>
                    <option *ngFor = "let c of categories$ | async " [value]="c.name">
                        {{c.name}}
                    </option> 
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf= "category.touched && category.invalid">
                    Category is required.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]= "product.imageUrl" name ="imageUrl" id ="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="https://.*" >
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image Url is required.</div>
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.pattern">Enter a valid Url.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input #description= "ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "product.description" name = "description" id ="description" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="description.touched && description.invalid">
                    description is required. 
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Product-form.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent {

  categories$;
  product:any = {};
  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService, 
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   
      this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

      let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      if (id) this.productService.get(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);

  }

  save(product){
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products'])
  }

}
```

Lastly My product service is given as
(product.service.ts) -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    this.db.list('/products ').push(product); 
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products ').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( action => {
      return action.map(product => {
        const key = product.payload.key;
        const data = product.payload.val();
        return  data;
      })
     } )); 
  }

  get(productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }
}
```

The exported firebase data.json file-

```
{
  "categories": {
    "action": {
      "name": "Action"
    },
    "adventure": {
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    "fighting": {
      "name": "Fighting"
    },
    "puzzle": {
      "name": "Puzzle"
    },
    "strategy": {
      "name": "Strategy"
    }
  },
  "products ": {
    "-NdjCd4DNpztAOwiR1Hk": {
      "category": "Action",
      "imageUrl": "https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1888160/ss_549f55589c10866bc31243d277324e31ad155b29.600x338.jpg?t=1694077391",
      "price": 3599,
      "title": "ARMORED CORE™ VI FIRES OF RUBICON™"
    },
    "-Ndu1DegkAnM2FWqx1tu": {
      "category": "Action",
      "description": "In space, no one can hear you scream … except your friends! Rally your crew, man your spaceship, and prepare for an epic adventure. Battle fearsome foes, salvage valuable loot, die repeatedly - while reclaiming humanity's lost territory together.",
      "imageUrl": "https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/1063420/header.jpg?t=1694177016",
      "price": 2999,
      "title": "Void Crew"
    }
  }
```

Page view before clicking edit
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbdlG.png)

Page view after clicking edit (also do note the  url) -
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbKV.png)

Comment: I'm actively looking for the solution. Any feedback or help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue, actually in my firebase products node, there is an extra space at the end which was causing the issue.

Thus, correcting this in my `product.service.ts` file, corrected the issue.

```js
get(productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
}
```